# Conditioning Statement on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I'm not sure what ifThen statement or condition statement I may need for this one. Any help would be appreciated. I want to make the whole row red if I insert price into Sold column. F2 is my sold column.

Answer (score 2):

*KEY: Highlight all cells you want this to impact since conditional formatting only affects a single cell.

HOME -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule
Select a Rule Type: "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
Format values where this formula is true: "=NOT(ISBLANK($F1))"
Format button : Fill tab - Red
OK
OK

The $F1 anchors the rule to column F and allows the row number to fluctuate depending on which row the formula is being evaluated for

Comment: What would the condition statement be if I wanted all my sold items to go red in column F, but leave the ones un-shaded that have the word "Received" also in column F? Also my percentage calculation for profit is, profit * 100. Is this the proper formula? As it's giving me odd numbers, and I'm looking for a way to make it say 200% profit, etc.

Comment: For the first part, same process as above, but use the formula:
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($F1)), IF($F1="Received",0,1),0)

For the second part, I'm not sure; you might put that in its own question defining what 'Profit' is, and what your attempts are yielding

Comment: =IF(NOT(ISBLANK($F1)), IF($F1="Received",0,1),0), does not work, neither does IF($F1="Received",0,1),0) for what I'm looking for.

Comment: That first conditional formula does work. Were you sure to set the fill color?  I've tried it in three different workbooks now and works for full row conditioning, and single column conditioning.

Comment: Correct, the first one does worth, but the one where it should not highlight the ones with "Received" in the Sold column, does not.

Comment: No, I meant the formula modified for the word Received one works also. The only way to see what the problem is, is if you upload your file and/or get some pics uploaded of your cells and conditional formatting screens to verify what's happening.