# Using A Conditioning Statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Tried using statement =NOT($F2="Received"), but it still highlights everything. To start from the beginning because none of these are working, I am looking to highlight everything in red that has been sold, F column, that has a number, but exclude/don't highlight anything that is blank or has the word "Received" in it. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditioning Statement on Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/916295/conditioning-statement-on-excel)

Comment: You need to make sure that F2 I'd the upper left most cell in the applies to range.  Otherwise, Excel will treat that as a offset and evaluate the wrong cell.  For example, if in the applies to box is A1 first, then the conditional formatting will look at $F2 even though you probably want $F1.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the formula some from the last Q/A for this, so as you say, starting from the beginning (NOTE: it is case-sensitive for "Received"):

1. Highlight all cells you want to be turned red if column F contains a #
2. Create a new conditional formatting rule
3. Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Enter this formula and select the red fill color

> =IF($F2="Received",0,IF(ISBLANK($F2),0,1))

5. Click OK

[image]

Comment: do you have an email I can send you the Excel sheet?

Comment: Safer to throw it on dropbox (or something similar) in a public folder and send me a link, methinks